# How to maintain WebGL Canvas aspect ratio?

Tags: canvas, opengl-es, webgl

I have a Canvas which I'm drawing to via WebGl.
My Canvas is sized: 640 width x 480 height.

Im drawing a simple square in the middle. However I was surprised to find that when it is drawn it looks a little stretched horizontally.

What do i need to do to make this square look proper (no stretching)?
Note that I have not played with any viewport settings. Im just going thru the early WebGL tutorials.

Comment: Can you post your code? We don't know exactly how you're drawing your square, whether you are doing things like a perspective transform or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left edge of the canvas has x = -1.0, right has x = +1.0, top edge has y = 1.0 and bottom edge has coordinate of y = -1.0.

In another words, coordinates are normalized across the viewport (xy, z-coord is handled slightly different). Such coordinates are in the clipspace.

The ratio between the width and the height of the viewport is known as aspect ratio.
Aspect ratio is used when constructing the *projection matrix*.

When you don't use projection matrix to transform your coordinates into clipspace, you are then directly providing coordinates that will, depending on the size of the viewport, be scaled accordingly.

Find more details about projecton matrices [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) and [here](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/).

To solve your problem, simply divide x-coord with aspect ratio.

Comment: Links you have provided direct to same url. I guess it's something you didn't want. Anyway this reference is awesome, exactly something I was looking for! +1

Comment: Edited. Second link tends to load slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you drawing a square in 2d or 3d? It's hard to know how to help without seeing your code.

[These tutorials generally go over both the 2d and 3d case](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/).

The short answer is in WebGL drawing the canvas is always in the -1 to +1 space from left to right and -1 to +1 space from bottom to top.

So for example if your canvas is 300x150 and you want to draw a rectangle 10x20 pixels at 30,40 you'd somehow have to set `gl_Position` for each of the 4 vertices to

```
clipSpaceX = pixelSpaceX * 2 / canvasWidth  - 1
clipSpaceY = pixelSpaceY * 2 / canvasHeight - 1
```

Note: That math will be with y at the lower left corner of the canvas. Flip y if you want 0 at the top of the canvas.

```
clipSpaceY = -(pixelSpaceY * 2 / canvasHeight - 1)
```

But there's an infinite number of ways to get those results. To name just a few (1) pass in clipspace coordinates computed in JavaScript (2) pass pixel space coordinates and do the math above in the shader (3) pass in a unit square and do the math to expand it to the size you want.

It's really up to you.